# Effects with multiple actions angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, effects, ngrx-effects

I am trying to create an effect which gather info from store `(this.libraryReferencesStoreFacade.selectSelectedRows$)` loops through it, and finally make multiple calls to another action `(LibraryReferencesActions.patch({pathParameters: { id: 120},request: { id: row.id, group: 26 }})`.

I tried the below code but without success, please help me ?

```
@Effect()
    someEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(LibraryReferencesActions.createGroupSuccess),
        withLatestFrom(this.libraryReferencesStoreFacade.selectSelectedRows$),
        switchMap(([, rows]) => {
            console.log(rows,"")
            let Observables: Array<Observable<any>> = [];
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                Observables.push(
                    LibraryReferencesActions.patch({
                        pathParameters: { id: 120 },
                        request: { id: row.id, group: 26 },
                    })
                );
            });
                const observables: Array<Observable<any>> = Observables;
                return forkJoin(observables).map(result => new 
                LibraryReferencesActions.refreshList())
            }
        })
    )
```

also tried:

```
addGroupToLib$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(LibraryReferencesActions.createGroupSuccess),
        withLatestFrom(this.libraryReferencesStoreFacade.selectSelectedRows$),
        map(([, rows]) => {
            let Observables: any = [];
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                Observables.push(
                    LibraryReferencesActions.patch({
                        pathParameters: { id: 120 },
                        request: { id: 120, group: 26 },
                    })
                );
            });
            forkJoin(Observables).pipe(
                map(() => {
                    return LibraryReferencesActions.refreshList();
                })
            );
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: did you try to `return Observables`? if you'd provide stackblitz example you'd probably get answer pretty quickly ;)

Comment: remember you need subscribe to observables to executed (or use pipe async). BTW, in de last map -the belong to forkJoin, you do nothing with the response `result` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just add the `refreshList` action to the end of the array of `patch` actions and they should run in order:

```js
addGroupToLib$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LibraryReferencesActions.createGroupSuccess),
    withLatestFrom(this.libraryReferencesStoreFacade.selectSelectedRows$),
    switchMap(([, rows]) => {
      return rows
        .map(row => {
          return LibraryReferencesActions.patch({
            pathParameters: { id: 120 },
            request: { id: row.id, group: 26 }
          })
        })
        .concat(
          LibraryReferencesActions.refreshList()
        )
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Concat did not work, but everything else works. Thanks! If you know a way to concat the refresh I would appreciate also. But as a work around I added a effect for the patch action to refresh when succeded.